# Factory Restore using HP Recovery vs Windows Refresh/Reset

Tags: windows-10, reset, hp-pavilion, display-driver, windows-8-refresh

I am having some display driver trouble with my Windows 10 HP laptop, and after multiple rounds of support from Costco and HP, I was told to just factory reset my laptop. I was given instructions to rapidly pres `F11` when booting, and then select system recovery. From there I was to select System reset or something like that. How is this any different from Windows 10's built in refresh or reset mechanism? I understand that refresh will leave my files intact, and just reinstall Windows 10, and refresh will fully remove everything. Can I perform a refresh instead of a factory reset?

Thanks in advance,
vikarjramun

Answer (score 0):

Factory restore using HP supplied media or from a hidden recovery partition wipes out everything / reimages the drive. That means all the pre-installed stuff will be back along with the Operating System.

Resetting Windows would fix incorrect settings or system file corruption issues, but won't bring back the device and chipset drivers, OEM pre-installed applications which you may have uninstalled earlier.

Whether to do a Windows Refresh/Reset or Factory Restore. It's really your call.